# Disable PivotItem transition animation

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to disable the PivotItem transition animation when i select one programmatically, because I don't want the user see "crazy" transitions between much element.
How can I do?

Comment: You'll just have to go pull them out of the `VisualStateManager` for that control's template.

Answer (score 0):

Set them to the *Selected* state programmatically before you actually select them:

```
var pivotItem = (PivotItem) pivotController.
                ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1);
VisualStateManager.GoToState(pivotItem, "Selected", useTransitions : false);
pivotController.SelectedIndex(1);
```

[Edit] I think my answer is not valid (I'm not developing for the phone) because as far as I understood the [msdn docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivotitem) there is no *Selected* state.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code, but select() function doesn't exists for pivotitem class. If I select it with pivot controller .SelectedIndex = x, the animation is showed.

Comment: @Eghes: How do you retrieve the `PivotItems` that you want to select programatically? If you are able to get a reference to an item and know the exact name of the `VisualState` you can set it before you select it. My code sample is meant as "just to get the idea", I don't know what method you call to select programmatically.

Comment: Being a binding pivot controller, I get the pivoitem by doing PivotItem pivotitem = (PivotItem)pivotcontroller.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1); 
If I do pivotitem.Select(), the method doesn't exists. If I use pivotcontroller.SelectedIndex(1) the animation is runned.